# Using wget to download/delete file?

Tags: php, cron

This is what I'm currently using to wget a website with a cron job:

```
wget http://www.example.com
```

What this does is download a copy of index.html to my server.  If index.html already exists, then it will name new files like index.html.1, index.html.2, index.html.3, and so on.

Is there a way to wget with a cron job and overwrite any existing files with that name so that only the most recent download is kept?

Comment: The same as without cron? ;-P

Comment: why not just put `rm index.html` into your cron job? wget's job is to fetch things, not clean up the mess you made with it.

Comment: you mean like `rm index.html wget http://www.example.com`?